# How to store the multiline - data from WPF-text box into SQL server and retrieve it from SQL without changing the format?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am just the beginner in VB.NET. I was trying to store the data from WPF-Text box into SQL server and retrieving the data from SQL using VB.NET. I am able to store the date into SQL. But when i am retrieving the data from SQL, the format of the text is getting changed (I have stored the data in multiple lines, but while retrieving, they are retrieved as single paragraph). I have already set the WPF textbox properties into multiline. But i cant find the solution to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant part of the code? It will be hard to answer without it.

Comment: what do you mean by "I have stored the data in multiple lines"? you store lines in separate rows??